# VBA Dim and Set Range global

Tags: vba, set, range, global

I have a probably easy problem using variables globally:

I want to Dim and Set various ranges in order to use them in different subs.
Simple Example given:

```
    Sub Variables()

    Dim rng1 as Range
    Set rng1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells
    Dim rng2 as Range
    Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells

    End Sub
```

Then in order to use my variables in other subs I tried to call my Variable sub, like:

```
    Sub calc()

    Call Variables

    Dim i as Integer
    i = rng1.Find("Hello").Column


    With Sheet1.Cells(1, i)
         .Value = "World"
    End With
```

I get the Error "Object required". I also tried to define my Variables as Public Sub but it still doesn't work.

I hope you know how to solve this problem or how to give a different approach!

Thanks!

Comment: Don't do this. Use the CodeName of the worksheet instead.

Comment: i.e., change `rng1.Find("Hello").column` to `Sheet1.Find("Hello").Column` just like you have in the `With Sheet1...` statement below it.

Comment: Thank you, but that was just a very simple example. In the application I program I have like 20 Sheets and at least 30 different ranges, which need in different subs so I have to this in order to keep my code clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

Sub Variables()

    Set rng1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells
    Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells

End Sub

Sub calc()

    Variables

    Dim i As Integer
    i = rng1.Find("Hello").Column

    Sheet1.Cells(1, i).Value = "World"

End Sub
```

You declared inside the Sub, you can't able to use them in other Sub, so that's why it gives you an error.

The solution here is put them at the top of your Procedure.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I get the exact same Error with your code

Comment: @jan So you want to access them in any Procedure (Sheet, Workbook, Module, etc etc etc)?

Comment: Sorry the method does work! I just defined the variables in an other Module so I had to use Public and not Dim. My bad, thanks!